# How to play server m3u file directly without download in android

Tags: android, server, audio-streaming

In my application I want to play server m3u file directly with out downloading the file. For this i am using bellow code

```
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();`enter code here`
```

But did not work.
this is the server url file
http://stream.abacast.net/playlist/mwfmadison-wrisfmmp3-ibc3.m3u.

So can any one please how to do this

Comment: As far as I know, you can't.  It's (sadly) not one of the supported types.  Fortunately, the file format is incredibly easy to parse and handle on your own, so I'd just recommend doing that.

Comment: I am trying as well to play m3u file and I cannot

Comment: Hello did you find a way to do it ?